# Group H is normal in Group G, Group K is normal in G, K not necessarily normal in G

Tags: finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Currently I am trying to understand the concept of groups, subgroups and normal groups. As each of the these definitions are clear to me, I can't verify the statement given in the Title:

I already came across a sketch for verification. However I still have troubles writing everything down without error.

Thus far I got: 
http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normality_is_not_transitive#List_of_counterexamples_of_small_order

I pick G as my D8 group, listed here: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Dihedral_group:D8

Then I pick my Klein Four group H: {1,a,b,c}

And take a normal subset K = {1,a} of H

I think one has to care that all elements of the sets are named correctly as the referenced sides use different notations, but that shouldn't make a problem.

I can verify: K is normal in H.

However I can't verify: H is normal in G. K is not normal in G.

I would be very happy, if someone could help me nailing this issue as this would probably help quite a lot understanding the basics of Algebra.

Comment: Title says "$G$ not necessarily normal in $G$"??

Comment: The title has to be modified. At present it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** A subgroup of index $2$ is always normal (this is typically "exercise 1" in textbooks introducing the concept).

For $K\not\lhd G$ it suffices to find $x\in G$ with $xax^{-1}\ne a$.

Comment: Yeah, by definition this suffices. However my problem is that I fail assigning the correct element of the subsets, H and K. Once I had them, I knew what to do. For example the table shown in Link 1. just uses the variables "a" and "x" ; I think one table for the Klein Four Group would be enough..